# Cannot sign into Visual Studio

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I know there are other questions on this, but none of their suggestions work.

I have Visual Studio Community 2015 and I am running Windows 10. When I try and sign into it, I cannot and get the error "SP324099: Could not complete the operation" and it takes me to [this URL](https://app.vsaex.visualstudio.com/profile/create?compact=1&mkt=en-US&reply_to=https%3A%2F%2Fapp.vssps.visualstudio.com%2F_signedin%3Frealm%3Dapp.vssps.visualstudio.com%26protocol%3Djavascriptnotify%26reply_to%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fapp.vssps.visualstudio.com%252F_apis%252FconnectionData%253FconnectOptions%253DIncludeServices%2526lastChangeId%253D-1%2526lastChangeId64%253D-1&campaign=o~msft~vside~service_attach_new_user&cs=Community&cv=14.102.25619.0%20&context=eyJwZSI6MCwicGMiOjEsImljIjoxLCJhbyI6MCwiYW0iOjAsIm9wIjoxLCJmYSI6MCwiY3YiOjE3ODUxMTY2MDMsImZzIjoyLCJzdSI6MSwiZXIiOjB90) which just says "this page cannot be displayed.

I used internet explorer 11.

The reason why I have to use Visual Studio is because my professor is giving us assignments that specifically pertain to Visual Studio and cannot be done on another IDE

Comment: I have seen that when running on an old NT4 domain (samba). Although the Visual Studio IDE still worked without the login. I don't use any of the cloud features.

Comment: Ja. Didn't even know you COULD log in.

Comment: using a proxy? I had trouble with vs2015, compared to previous versions. As it uses a https sign in page as opposed to http with the previous versions of vs2015. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31571224/visual-studio-2015-cant-sign-in-use-nuget-etc-behind-corporate-proxy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled VS and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem typing internet options (in windows search), in tab advanced i checked SSL 3.0, TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2.