# NuGET Issue. How to install Packages without Nuget

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, package-managers

What happen to nuget today? Are they out? I was not able to download everything using VS or even the browser was not able to download

https://api.nuget.org/packages/entityframework.6.1.3.nupkg

Browser returned:

> This site can’t be reached api.nuget.org’s server DNS address could
>   not be found. Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.

VS returned:

```
Error occured:\nAn error occurred while sending the request.
```

Package Manager Console returned:

```
install-package : An error occurred while sending the request.
At line:1 char:1
+ install-package entityframework
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

Any idea? Please help. Thanks

Comment: try google DNS server: https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/

Comment: What's the result if you run command "ping api.nuget.org"?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use nuget but have access to the package you want, you could just add the package files into your project directory and then add the references in by right clicking on them in the solution directory and then clicking add reference

Comment: this post solved mine: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32580272/7352691 thanks for the your help.

Comment: let me revert this comment, since it worked for a bit allowing me to add EF6 and AngularJs packages and then it did not worked again. I think something is blocking my request using this: https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

Comment: response:  DNS Lookup for "api.nuget.org" failed. System.Net.Sockets.SocketException

Answer (score 0):

Doubt if there is any issues with the nuget site, it seems to be resolving fine. There might be proxy which is blocking.

If you are behind any corporate firewall for nuget which is causing issues, host your nuget service. However you need to figure out how to download the package once, to push it to your own host.

[Host your own nuget](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToHostYourOwnNuGetServerAndPackageFeed.aspx)

Comment: I am working home based just a day or two, I was able to download using using NUGET Package Manager but not until today.

Comment: Although I have previous project having those packages, I might try to Host My own nuget. I will try. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@CodeJammer, I agree with Pacchy's suggestion.

Please check your machine have any proxy configured or "http_proxy" variable configured in environment variable. If yes, you need to add proxy settings into Nuget.Config file. Refer to this link for details: [Nuget Config Section](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/schema/nuget.config-file#config-section) & [Nuget Proxy Settings](http://skolima.blogspot.sg/2012/07/nuget-proxy-settings.html). Alternatively, you can clear the Proxy Cache in IE and "http_proxy" environment variable, see [How to reset your Internet Explorer proxy settings](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2289942).

If the NuGet issue persists, you can try to Host Your own nuget or download the NuGet package and unzip it to local folder, which will list all content of this package. Then add the dlls in the unzipped folder into your project through Add Reference.

Comment: If I could not even download any package even using the browser, hosting my own nuget may not be possible.

Comment: https://api.nuget.org/packages/entityframework.6.1.3.nupkg displays error

Comment: This site can’t be reached

api.nuget.org’s server DNS address could not be found.
Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.

Comment: I think this has something to do with Postman, since after I have installed that software, I cannot download anything from nuget but anything else works fine though. Browsing and downloading from other sites works as if there were no issue at all

Comment: @ CodeJammer, could you visit the https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json over other browser except for Chrome? Could you uninstall or disable the Postman, then download nuget package again?
If nuget can work successfully after you disable or uninstall the Postman, you can try to configuring your DNS servers to solve this issue.

Comment: I have tried to make a Get request with fiddler and the following is the response: [Fiddler] DNS Lookup for "api.nuget.org" failed. System.Net.Sockets.SocketException This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server

Comment: @ CodeJammer, which browser did you use? For example, could you test in IE browser if  you used the Chrome before? Like this video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OHNBp-hhUR0, please check your "change proxy settings". In addition, if you just install certain software(Postman) before it worked well, I suggest you disable it, so we could narrow down this issue.