# Visual Studio no internet connection

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

i installed visual studio 2015 , but i can't sign in , not even connect to tfs server , i tried to stop the firewall and to repair the VS and i tried many internet connection and provider  but nothing worked , even i tried the below solution : 
[Visual Studio 2015 - Can't sign in, Use NuGet, etc. behind corporate proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31571224/visual-studio-2015-cant-sign-in-use-nuget-etc-behind-corporate-proxy)

please any suggestion ? im trying since 3 days to fix this issue i can provide you team viewer access if someone can help me

thanks in advance

Comment: Is your network cable unplugged? :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not programming related (sorry).

Comment: Visual Studio and tfs project are not related to programming ?:) @christian.k

Comment: In your case - I'd say they are not. You seem to have a technical issue that cannot really be reproduced and thus answers would be mostly guesswork. You might be better off in the respective Microsoft support forums, for example [this one](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-us/home?forum=visualstudiogeneral)). Not that I don't sympathize with your pain though ;-)

Comment: @Christian.K It's on-topic: "a specific programming problem, or
a software algorithm, or
**software tools commonly used by programmers**; and is
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development
… then you’re in the right place to ask your question!"

Comment: @DanielMann my reasoning was exactly about the "practical, answerable problem that is _unique_ to software development" (emphasize added) - in IMHO it is not, as it stands anyway. But then people have different opinions, that is why 4 close votes are needed.

Comment: What's the error you get when you connect to TFS? Could the TFS be connect from browser(http://serverName:8080/tfs)?

Comment: Hello , yes im able to connecr from browser , and when im clicking on open with VS i got internet connection errror

Comment: Please clean the cache and try again: C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\6.0\Cache. Could you please share the detail error message here.

Comment: i tried to clear the cache and nothing changed , the error :
Sorry we ran into a problem 
the online service is not available . Please try again later 
See our current service status 

and this error is shown directly after clicking on the sign in button

i can give you team viewer access if needed

Answer (score 0):

Solved , uninstall Kaspersky :)